# Change custom fields of Identity User

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Hey I added Teams to my ApplicationUser like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here

        return userIdentity;
    }


    public virtual ICollection<Function> Functions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Participation> Participations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}
```

In my Controller I want to add a new Team for the user:

```
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.GetUserById(dto.PersonId[0]);
if (user != null)
{
    if (user.Teams == null)
    {
        user.Teams = new List<Team>();
    }
    user.Teams.Add(mannschaft);
    mannschaft.UsersId.Add(user?.Id);
    uow.SaveChanges();
    Team team = uow.RepTeam.Get(t => t.Bezeichnung == dto.Name).FirstOrDefault();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, team?.Id);
}
```

So theres no problem the team got added to the IdentityUser but when I want to call all teams in a different Controller like this:

```
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.GetUserById(userid);
ICollection<DtoTeam> foo = new List<DtoTeam>();
if (user != null)
{
    foreach (var teams in user.Teams)
    {
        foo.Add(uow.RepTeam.GetByKey(teams).ToDto());
    }
}
return foo;
```

It says that there are no teams in the user...

Comment: You are mixing contexts. There is your Identity context (which contains the AspNet... tables) and there is your Custom context, which should contain tables like user, team, function, participant. Identity is about identifying the user. This has nothing to do with your custom context. You should try to seperate these concerns.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I get it but in my application  a user can be in a team so should i add a new Entity person where I save the identity id AND the teams and so on? I already thought about this solution but did not know if its good.

Comment: Yes, setup a seperate custom model with its own user table. Strictly speaking the identity model is only about Identity. You may even store the Identity tables in a different database, or you can use an external service to login (like IdentityServer). So the custom model actually knows nothing about the identity and the Identity model knows nothing about the custom model. This means that there is no relation between the two. Except that you can link the login user to the custom user. You can do this by adding a claim with the userid.

Comment: Yeah did it and works!! Gonna try to save the identity user tables in a seperate database now. All I have to do that is to change the connection string of the identity user context. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. You'll need two connectionstrings, one for the Identity context and one for your custom context. You don't have to store the identity tables in a seperate database though.

Answer (score 0):

IMO , you still can use your table and remove the autogenerate table like Aspnet..Table or whatever

and if you want to save your data you can change path like identityUser to your table using OnmodelCreating()

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("your_table_name");           
    }
```

any advance you can search google